# How to extract the last message from a tracback and keep original stack trace

Tags: python-3.x, rest

I have a python script that uses try/except and calls other functions. I would like to use traceback to capture the stack trace, but also need to separate the final ( or last) error message in the stack trace so that the final message can be clearly displayed on an API call return.

Below is an example of a function, There are several try/excepts that are wrapped in one overatching try execept. Instead of having so many returns, I would like to condense the traceback message from all the excepts and only have one return statement.

Not sure if this is possible?

```
def get(clean_event):

try:
    if clean_event["resource"] == "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
        try:
            study_id = clean_event["pathParameters"]["studyid"]
        except:
            message = "ERROR: unable to get study id from path parameter."
            return cb.return_to_caller(message=message,
                                       stack_trace=traceback.format_exc(),
                                       status_code=HTTP_STATUS_CODE.ERROR.value,
                                       cors=CORSVAR)

        try: 
            fx_name = "study.get_notes"
            fx_params = [None, study_id]

            return cb.common_get(clean_event['headers'],
                                 clean_event['queryStringParameters'],
                                 clean_event['pathParameters'], fx_name, fx_params
                                 )
        except:
            message = "ERROR: unable to execute function ({}) using study_id ({}).".format(
                fx_name, fx_params)

    elif clean_event["resource"] == "xxxxxxxxx":
        try:
            note_id = clean_event["pathParameters"]["noteid"]
        except:
            message = "ERROR: unable to get note id from path parameter."
            return cb.return_to_caller(message=message,
                                       stack_trace=traceback.format_exc(),
                                       status_code=HTTP_STATUS_CODE.ERROR.value,
                                       cors=CORSVAR)

        try: 
            fx_name = "study.get_notes"
            fx_params = [note_id, None]

            return cb.common_get(clean_event['headers'],
                                 clean_event['queryStringParameters'],
                                 clean_event['pathParameters'], fx_name, fx_params,
                                 strip_outer_array=True
                                 )
        except:
            message = "ERROR: unable to execute function ({}) using study_id ({}).".format(
                fx_name, fx_params)

    else:
        message = "ERROR: no logic exists for resource being invoked."
        return cb.return_to_caller(message=message,
                                   stack_trace=traceback.format_exc(),
                                   status_code=HTTP_STATUS_CODE.ERROR.value,
                                   cors=CORSVAR)

except:
    message = "ERROR: unable to execute GET. Check traceback for details."
    return cb.return_to_caller(message=message,
                               stack_trace=traceback.format_exc(),
                               status_code=HTTP_STATUS_CODE.ERROR.value,
                               cors=CORSVAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use traceback.format_exc()

```
try:
 .
 .
except:
   stack_trace = traceback.format_exc().splitlines()
   print(stack_trace[0]) # first line in traceback
   print(stack_trace[-1]) # last line in the traceback
   # or to print everythoing
   print(stack_trace)
```

refer traceback module documentation for complete information.